# Show first selected row Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

For example:

```
id 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

I want to show first `id = 7` and after `10,9,8,6,5,4,3,2,1` . How to write this code with php ? Please help me `(Sorry for bad English)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL has a convenience where boolean expressions are treated as integers, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  A fast way to write this is:

```
order by (id = 7) desc, id desc
```

In other databases, you need to use `case` or similar logic.

Answer (score 1):

You could order by a specific `case` expression:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     mytable
ORDER BY CASE id WHEN 7 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, id DESC
```